# How to get filtered rows in react datagridpro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

After filtering data, how to get a hold of that filtered data. I am unable to find any prop to get that. Please find my code in sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/h7qji?file=/demo.js  (I am using react data grid pro.

I have gone through all the websites and found one, i.e., kendo-react-grid (onDataStateChange prop), but that is licensed.

Do we have any option to get that filtered data in react data grid pro ?